# Gatling Kotlin - extract value from first call's response and use on next

Tags: kotlin, gatling

I'm using `Gatling` with `kotlin`.

I have one endpoint that once I call it, it returns a value that I need to use on the next call to my second endpoint.

From what I have seen till now, I need to extract the value and store it in `gatling's` session and then retrieve. But I do not seem to be able to access the session and do an `exec` at the same time. Can someone please help me on how this should look like... Following is an example of almost how it is right now and how I would like to access the extracted value

```
exec(
    http("Start")
        .post("/start")
        .body(StringBody("""
                    {
                        "someKey": "someValue"
                    }
                """.trimIndent()))
        .check(jsonPath("$.valueToExtract").find().saveAs("valueToExtract"))
)
.exec { session ->
    val valueToExtract = session.getString("valueToExtract")
    valueToExtract = valueToExtract.substring(5)
    val newSession = session.set("valueToExtract", valueToExtract)
    newSession
}
.pause(1)
.exec(
    http("Second endpoint")
        .put("/v1/endpoint-two")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .body(StringBody("""
        {
            "extractedValue": "${session.get("valueToExtract")}" 
        }
    """.trimIndent()))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gatling Expression Language](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/el/):

```kotlin
("""
        {
            "extractedValue": "#{valueToExtract}" 
        }
    """
```

Note: you don't have to do this in 2 steps: you can directly pass a function to `StringBody` where you'd fetch the data, compute what you want and compute the string using interpolation:

```kotlin
StringBody{ session ->
  val valueToExtract = session.getString("valueToExtract").substring(5)

"""
        {
            "extractedValue": "$valueToExtract" 
        }
    """.trimIndent()
}
```